# Multiple Azure Container Instance groups on one fixed IP

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway, azure-container-instances

**Question:**
With the `az container create` command, I can create five container groups. However, they have different public IP's. I wish to make container `[i]` accessible from an URL like `???.???.???.???/container[i]`, where `???.???.???.???` is some fixed IP. How is this possible?

**My attempt at a solution:**
I think an Application Gateway is the solution. There is an [example (1) at the MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/tutorial-url-route-cli) of an Application Gateway with traffic based on the URL, and there is an [example (2) at the MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-application-gateway) of an Application Gateway for a container group. However, the solutions seem incompatible. They both start with creating a Virtual Network with a Subnet and a public IP. But then for the container group (2), the `az network application-gateway create` command is called with the parameter `--servers`, with the IP address of the container group. But for the traffic based solution (1), they do not use this parameter and go on creating *address-pools* and define *url-path-maps*. In that example they use vmss'es, which can be defined with `--app-gateway` and `--backend-pool-name`, but container groups do not have these parameters.

**Does anybody know how to get multiple container instance groups accessible on one URL? Thank you!**

Comment: Azure Container Instances allocates one IP address per container group. If you want to provide a single IP address for a group of container groups, you will need to implement a service layer above the container groups. Using a load balancer, proxy, etc. are typical solutions. A very simple solution is to deploy a VM and use something like HAProxy or Nginx. Your question does not cover details like HA, global/regional, service features, interface type, etc. For Stack Overflow, you research and create the solution. When you have a programming-related problem, post a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @John Hanley, Azure container instance allocates one ip address per container group and we don't any direct solution to use single URL to Multiple container groups.

And also Placing an Azure Load Balancer in front of container instances in a networked container group is not supported.
Container groups deployed to a virtual network don't currently support exposing containers directly to the internet with a public IP address or a fully qualified domain name.